# Keep scrollbar visible in Material dialog

Tags: angular-material

I have a dialog that can be long enough vertically to need a scroll bar. Angular material handles this automatically, but the scroll bar only appears while scrolling, so a user might not know that it's even possible to do so. Is there a way to make the scroll bar always appear if there is overflow in `mat-dialog-content`? Looking at the API, I thought this might be able to be done with `scrollStrategy`, but I can't seem to figure it out.